# keypress [tab, shift, up/down/left/right arrow] and firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, keypress

Firefox triggers the `keypress` callback function when `tab, shift, up/down/left/right arrow` keys are pressed, however, Chrome, Safari, IE do not.

Please refer [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/sarbbottam/pen/yOzyNJ?editors=0011).

Not only it triggers the call back function on `keypress` but also passes the `keyCode` as `0` when `tab, shift, up/down/left/right arrow` keys are pressed.

**I could**

```
var charCode = (typeof e.which === 'number') ? e.which : e.keyCode;
if (charCode === 0) return;
```

**but wondering, if its a bug in Firefox, rather why there is a inconsistency between Firefox and other browsers?**

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress:

> If supported by a user agent, this event must be dispatched when a key is pressed down, **if and only if that key normally produces a character value.**

By that last part I'd say, Firefox is handling this wrong - tab, shift and arrow keys do not "produce a character value."

(tab would produce a "character value" - even if not "visible", the tab character is still a character - in other environments, but in a web page in the browser it doesn't, but just skips to the next focusable element; so it has to be excluded from triggering the event as well.)

Comment: Looks like its a bug in `Firefox`